# Can i express someone must-do(modal verb) something with semantic web?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, rdfs, shacl

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb

whatever its in any form of rdf rdfs owl shacl etc...

someone do something vs someone "must"-do something

Sam go to school. Sam "must" go to school.

and another case is someone must do, but do what is not important.

?s ?p
?subject:Sam ?predict:shouldWork

Comment: I don't know what you asking here. The logic behind OWL is Description Logic which is a decidable subset of First Order Logic. That's all you can express - anything else is your modelling.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
ObjectProperty: attends
  Domain: Person

Class: School
Class: Person

Class: SchoolAgeChild
  SubClassOf: 
    Person,
    attends some School
```

which states that as a person of school age has to attend at least 1 school.

Then if you have an individual `sam` that of type `SchoolAgeChild` that is not attending a school, which you can specify as follows

```
Individual: sam
  Types: attends max 0 School
```

the reasoner will give an inconsistency. Also, the reasoner will infer that any individual that attends something is a person. However, you can create individuals of person that attends things or don't attend things.

As for dealing with doing tasks versus important tasks you will have to do something as follows

```
Class: Task
  DisjointUnionOf: ImportantTask, UnimportantTask  

Class: ImportantTask
  SubClassOf: Task
Class: UnimportantTask
  SubClassOf: Task

Class: Manager
 SubClassOf: attends some ImportantTask and attends only ImportantTask
```

which states that a manager attends to at least 1 important task and a manager only attends to important tasks.